# I need a clarification of targeting an element from the markup

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, queryselector, document-body

I am following a class online and the tutor target a `<button>` document in which I don't really understand how he did it because he used a `document.querySelector` to target the parent and that's all.

```html
<div class="row">
    <form id="task-form" action="index.php">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input type="text" name="task" id="task" value="">
            <label for="task">New Task</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="add" class="btn">Add</button>
</form>
```

he then wrote :

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) { /* ... */ })
```

to me what I understand is that the `querySelector` will only select the `firstChild` in this case.

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Comment: the button must be inside the form for the magic to happen

Answer (score 1):

The code just targets the `<form>` and adds a listener for the `submit` event.
It is not targeting any `<button>`.

Comment: @GMtech The `<button>` is just submitting the `<form>` with pure HTML.

Answer (score 0):

He actually doesn't add listeners to any button. What you confused was the `<form>` having an `onsubmit` event listener. Since there is only one button in the form, its `type` attribute is automatically set to `submit`, making it trigger the `form.onsubmit` event every time.

Also, the code is a bit wrong. You open a div, a form, and before closing the form, you close the div. If that was made by the person who runs the course, I would recommend to stop watching that course in general, since it can confuse a lot...

Comment: Thank you so much,this is a classic explanation,I get it now